# How to add bookmarks in Chromium/Chrome in automated fashion

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, puppeteer

I am trying to test a Chrome extension that searches bookmarks. Puppeteer loads Chromium with a clean profile each time, which is great, but my bookmarks are empty.

I was hoping to find a way to load a bookmarks file, so I don't have to use the Chrome API to manually create a bookmark tree under a testing flag in my code.

Comment: If you're going to use your rep to downvote, please comment a reason so I can correct the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load an existing user data directory with all of its data, including bookmarks and browser settings:

```
puppeteer.launch({
  userDataDir: '/path/to/user-data-directory',
})
```

The profile must be from a Chrome/Chromium version close to the puppeteer's Chromium.
Also — in my experience path shouldn't contain spaces on Windows.

Comment: Some things to note:
* Spaces worked for me, on macOS. `/Users/varr/Library/Application Support/Chromium`
* The user data directory is _not_ the profile directory in the user data directory (I made that mistake). https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md
* Having two profiles in my user data directory caused two separate Chromium windows to open with puppeteer, so I deleted them all but one.